# I'm coding a tower defense program in pygame. My code for spawning new waves is not working

Tags: python, pygame

Here is an except of code from my program. The first block deals with shot + enemy collision, the second with mine + enemy collision, the third with actually spawning the new waves. Currently, the initial wave size spawns 10 enemies and the game loop does not generate new enemies after the first wave.

```
        # baddie and shot collision
        removed = False
        for a in baddies[:]:
            for b in shots[:]:
                if a.imgRect.colliderect(b.imgRect):
                    shots.remove(b)
                    a.toughness -= 1
                    if a.toughness < 1:
                        baddies.remove(a)
                        removed = True

                        print str(wavesize)

                        break

        # baddie and mine collision
        removed = False
        for a in baddies[:]:
            for b in mines[:]:
                if a.imgRect.colliderect(b.imgRect):
                    mines.remove(b)
                    a.toughness -= 1
                    if a.toughness < 1:
                        baddies.remove(a)
                        removed = True
                        break

        if removed:
            wavesize -= 1
            if wavesize < 1:
                loopcount += 1
                wavesize = 10+(loopcount*5)
                baddies = createNewWave(wavesize)
```

Comment: Any chance you could add some logging to your code to show that the conditional statements are being hit as you expect? Also, I notice that you reset `removed` at the very beginning of your *mine collision* block, regardless of what the value had been following your *shot collision* block. This means you are ignoring the shots!

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or print statements?

Comment: Ok, with a print statement in the first block, the console is printing out only '10's (the initial wavesize). This makes me think the program isn't reading the third block at all.

Comment: Instead of tracking when enemies are removed, why not just directly check the length of your `baddies` list?

Answer (score 1):

You're only decreasing `wavesize` by one each time you run through the loops and you remove a baddie, but you very well may be removing more than one baddie at a time. Also, you're resetting your `removed` variable after the first set of loops, so you may be missing baddies if they are destroyed by shots. What you should do is keep track of how many baddies you remove, and then decrease the wave size by that many.

```
removed = 0
for a in baddies[:]:
    for b in shots[:]:
        ...
        baddies.remove(a)
        removed += 1

for a in baddies[:]:
    for b in mines[:]:
        ...
        baddies.remove(a)
        removed += 1

wavesize -= removed
if wavesize < 1:
    loopcount += 1
    wavesize = 10+(loopcount*5)
    baddies = createNewWave(wavesize)
```

Comment: Interesting. This does create waves, and it does increase the wave size every time, but it deletes the current wave and spawns the new wave upon every collision.